# .NET 8 & SQL Server 2016 - Contains() throws error

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0, ef-core-8.0

I decided to switch my project from `.NET6` to `.NE 8`. My project database is SQL Server 2016.

At first everything was going well, but I ran into a bug:

```
var seferIds = tList.expedition.Select(r => r.Key).ToArray();
var sql = (from h in context.Line
           join v in context.Route on h.id equals v.lineId
           join s in context.Expedition on v.id equals s.routeId
           where seferIds.Contains(s.id)
           select new { h, v, s })
          .ToDictionary(r => r.s.id);
```

In this way, I cannot use `Contains()` in Linq queries I created with my database tables (`AsQueryable`).

I did some research and if I define it as

```
where seferIds.AsQueryable().Contains(s.id)
```

the error disappears. At the same time, I need to do an empty check in the form of `seferIds.Any()` in my code.

I looked to see if I would get the same error using SQL Server 2019 as the database and `where seferIds.Contains(s.id)` works there without any problems and there is no error.

As for my question, is this problem that .net8 is no longer compatible with the old database version? Is there another situation that I missed.

I would like to know if there is a different solution for this error.

Comment: Why all those JOINs? This suggest EF is being misused. EF tries to give the impression of working with in-memory objects, not tables and rows. If the entities have proper properties and relations, EF will generate the necessary JOINs automatically. This entire query could be replaced with `context.Expeditions.Include(e=>e.Routes).ThenInclude(r=>r.Lines).Where(e=>seferIds.Contains(e.Id)).ToDictionary(e=>e.Id);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before updating your project to a newer version, be sure to read Breaking changes, your problem is also in this list:

[Breaking changes in EF Core 8 (EF8)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/breaking-changes)

The new `EF Core 8.0` translation uses the SQL Server [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function to instead transfer the values as a JSON array. This solves the performance issues inherent in the previous technique; however, the `OPENJSON` function is unavailable in SQL Server 2014 and below.

### solution:

The `OPENJSON` function was introduced in SQL Server 2016 (13.x);  To do this, simply call the new `UseCompatibilityLevel` method when configuring your context options The 120 argument is the desired SQL Server compatibility level; 120 corresponds to SQL Server 2014 (12.x). When this is done, EF will generate the previous translation.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseSqlServer(@"<CONNECTION STRING>", o => o.UseCompatibilityLevel(120));
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Mohammad Aghazadeh. Defining `o.UseCompatibilityLevel(120)` eliminated my problem.

Comment: Huh - [interesting technique](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef8-preview-4/) - I've always resorted to defining my own `CREATE TYPE AS TABLE` types and passing TVP data via `SqlCommand` + `SqlMetaData` - so using `OPENJSON` has considerable advantages as it doesn't need types statically defined - and lets us be more ad-hoc - though they admit `WHERE IN` might be faster, though so I'm curious how the performance  of `OPENJSON` compares to TVPs for datasets too big for RBAR while also not being large enough for `SqlBulkCopy` (e.g. between ~20 to 5,000 rows)

Comment: @B_Cbk Seeming as you're running SQL Server 2016 already, why not just update your database's compat-level to 130 so you can take-advantage of `OPENJSON`? It only takes ~5 seconds in SSMS - and I'm not aware of any significant compat problems requiring people to stick to 120.